# Hibernate Integrator Causes Flush When Using JPA Transactions Around Queries

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, integrator

I'm working on an `Integrator` for Hibernate (background on Integrators: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch14.html#objectstate-decl-security) that by using listeners is supposed to take my data from how it's stored in the DB and convert it into a different form for processing at runtime. This works great when saving the data using `.persist()` however there's an odd behavior involving transactions. The following code is from Hibernate's own [quickstart tutorial code](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/quickstart/en-US/html/files/hibernate-tutorials.zip):

```
// now lets pull events from the database and list them
entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
List<Event> result = entityManager.createQuery( "from Event", Event.class ).getResultList();
for ( Event event : result ) {
  System.out.println( "Event (" + event.getDate() + ") : " + event.getTitle() );
}
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
entityManager.close();
```

Notice the unusual transaction begin/commit wrapping the query to select the data. Running this gives the following output after the query completes:

```
01:01:59.111 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(175) - committing
01:01:59.112 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareEntityFlushes(149) - Processing flush-time cascades
01:01:59.112 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareCollectionFlushes(189) - Dirty checking collections
01:01:59.114 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.logFlushResults(123) - Flushed: 0 insertions, 2 updates, 0 deletions to 2 objects
01:01:59.114 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.logFlushResults(130) - Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 0 collections
01:01:59.114 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter.toString(114) - Listing entities:
01:01:59.114 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter.toString(121) - org.hibernate.tutorial.em.Event{date=2015-07-28 01:01:57.776, id=1, title=Our very first event!}
01:01:59.114 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter.toString(121) - org.hibernate.tutorial.em.Event{date=2015-07-28 01:01:58.746, id=2, title=A follow up event}
01:01:59.115 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL.logStatement(109) - update EVENTS set EVENT_DATE=?, title=? where id=?
Hibernate: update EVENTS set EVENT_DATE=?, title=? where id=?
01:01:59.119 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL.logStatement(109) - update EVENTS set EVENT_DATE=?, title=? where id=?
Hibernate: update EVENTS set EVENT_DATE=?, title=? where id=?
01:01:59.120 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doCommit(113) - committed JDBC Connection
01:01:59.120 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.close(201) - HHH000420: Closing un-released batch
01:01:59.121 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.releaseConnection(246) - Releasing JDBC connection
01:01:59.121 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.releaseConnection(264) - Released JDBC connection
01:01:59.121 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.close(1339) - HHH000031: Closing
```

It appears that since the `Integrator` does a modification on the entity in question it gets marked as "dirty" and upon committing this odd transaction, it bypasses my event listeners and writes the value back in the wrong format! I did some digging in the code and it turns out that `org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(FlushEvent, PersistenceContext)` gets called above and tries to get listeners for `EventType.FLUSH_ENTITY`. Unfortunately a listener added for this `EventType` is never called in my `Integrator`. How can I write my `Integrator` to behave correctly in this case so that I can "undo" the conversion that has happened with my entities at runtime and not flush the wrong value out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately the problem was due to the `EventType`s of the event listeners added with the `EventListenerRegistry`. What worked was using `EventType.POST_LOAD` for all the read operations combined with `EventType.PRE_UPDATE` and `EventType.PRE_INSERT` for writes that call a helper method for handling both the same way.

To prevent unneeded writes after making your entity updates it's a good idea to reset the data used for tracking if the entity is dirty in `EntityEntry` called `loadedState`. This is a private field in Hibernate 4 so you'll need to use Reflection, however in Hibernate 5 it's available via the `getLoadedState()` method. One more gotcha is you need to update values of the "state" used when actually flushing the values to the database by the `PreInsertEvent` and `PreUpdateEvent` which can be retrieved from the `getState()` method defined in each.